# custom module cannot find index action

Tags: magento-1.7, module

I am creating my first custom module for magento and I already have some issues. 
What I am trying to do is to create new section under catalog tab in admin panel (this I already made) but when I clicked my custom section it does not finds route (or in other words  it not finds index action) and I get redirected to 404 error page.

Here is what I already have:
app/etc/modules/Company_myModule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_myModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_myModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Company/myModule/controllers/Adminhtml/ReportController.php

```
<?php

class Company_myModule_Adminhtml_ReportController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
    echo "test";
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Company/myModule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_myModule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_myModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Company_myModule>
                <class>Company_myModule_Helper</class>
            </Company_myModule>
        </helpers>
    </global>   
</config>
```

app/code/local/Company/myModule/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog>
             <children>
                <myModule translate="title" module="company_myModule">
                    <title>myModule title</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>     
        <action>adminhtml/report</action>
                </myModule>
             </children>
    </catalog>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <catalog>
                    <title>myModule title</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                </catalog>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

Any ideas why it not able to find route to my index action in ReportController ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a Helper

`app/code/local/Company/myModule/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class Company_myModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Also, you'll need to add a router to your page in config.xml, like this:

```
....
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_myModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_myModule_Adminhtml</Company_myModule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
....
```

Comment: There is a user on StackExchange called Marius who also developed something extremely impressive for helping you set up new modules, have a look: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator.html

I find that the MagentoCommerce boards offer extremely useful & accurate guides:
http://tinyurl.com/3f7wpxs

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste my helper file. But you was right I was missing router in my config.xml file and adding it helped me solve the problem. Thanks, you saved my time ;) Also thanks for the useful resources. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the router declaration in your module.
In `config.xml` add this as a sibling node for `<global>`.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_myModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_myModule_Adminhtml</Company_myModule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

And make sure you place your controller in `app/code/local/Company/myModule/controllers/Adminhtml/ReportController.php`.
I also suggest not naming your controller `ReportController.php` there is already a file with that name in `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers` and your controller might override the core one.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, you and moose both was right telling that I was missing route in my module. Thanks for advice naming my controller, I will rename it :)